# Combine files in TopoJSON when one is simplified differently to the other

Tags: geojson, simplify, topojson

I have two .shp files, I am separately  converting these to GeoJSON with ogr2ogr.exe and then combining the files with TopoJSON.
Each file independently becomes a ~200kb topojson file, however the combined file is over 2mb.

It appears that one of the shapefiles has already been simplified slightly and so topojson is not finding a good correlation between the coastline arcs.

Other than trying to get a unsimplified source file, is there anything I can do to help topojson combine these files better?